# Semantics of relative URLs in schema.org Breadcrumbs in JSON-LD

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

The [schema.org website gives an example of a breadcrumb represented in JSON-LD](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList)

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
 "itemListElement":
 [
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 1,
   "item":
   {
    "@id": "https://example.com/dresses",
    "name": "Dresses"
    }
  },
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 2,
  "item":
   {
     "@id": "https://example.com/dresses/real",
     "name": "Real Dresses"
   }
  }
 ]
}
</script>
```

Most of it is clear to me but I'm not absolutely certain about the semantics of the links provided in this example.

What I find confusing are the `@id` properties. Their values are URLs and it looks like these should lead to actual web pages linked to by the breadcrumb items. However, the name of the property suggests that the URLs might actually point to concept identifiers in some ontology. Which is it?

The *Without Markup* tab contains an unannotated piece of HTML suggesting that my first guess is correct and the URLs actually lead to web pages.

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com/dresses">Dresses</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://example.com/dresses/real">Real Dresses</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Is this the case and is it okay to use relative URLs in this context?**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "http://schema.org",
 "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
 "itemListElement":
 [
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
   "position": 1,
   "item":
   {
    "@id": "https://dresses.com/dresses",
    "name": "Dresses"
    }
  },
  {
   "@type": "ListItem",
  "position": 2,
  "item":
   {
     "@id": "/dresses/cocktail",
     "name": "Cocktail Dresses"
   }
  }
 ]
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the case and is it okay to use relative URLs in this context?

Over at GitLab, we were confused by this too (see [relevant issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/281378)) since [Google's Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) blows up with relative URL's, **but** there are historic examples of relative URL's working in production.

So, we tried it out. We pushed some `json+ld` with relative URL's to production and one of our engineers [received an alert that the id field was invalid](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/281378#note_447280330).

Short answer - no it is not okay to use relative URL's for json+ld (but is okay to have relative URL's for markup, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434422/semantics-of-relative-urls-in-schema-org-breadcrumbs-in-json-ld/54963017#comment114719685_54963017)) and Google clearly expects absolute URL's. If it happens to work now, there's no guarantee that it will in the future.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing this out. Am I right to understand that GitLab changed from relative to absolute URLs, at which point Google started picking up the results? That's more convincing than a validator not throwing errors. Google could also be more explicit in their docs if that's a requirement.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz, yes your understand is right. We originally had no structured data for our breadcrumbs, but recently did an experiment which proved to us that absolute URL's were required. Lesson learned: try not to deviate too far from the examples :|

Answer (score 11):

I had the same question and end up doing research which I documented on https://sergeyski.com/relative-urls-in-structured-data/. Key part is this:

> If you paste markup directly into google validator and there is a
> relative path - validator doesn't know which domain it belongs to and
> just appends its own domain (https://search.google.com). Once you deploy changes and test with
> real url you'll see that validator will append correct domain, so you
> can definitely use relative urls in structured data.

Comment: Heads up! This answer seems to be no longer accurate. In our experience we got errors even in a deployed environment using relative URL's. Absolute URL's seem to be the expected standard so it's probably best to stick with those.

Comment: @souldzin I just double checked test from the article and I do not get errors both using old structure testing tool and using new rich results test tool.

Comment: I can't seem to find a test on the article using json-ld and/or with a structured data needing `@id`, so maybe that context is important?

Comment: @souldzin I think you're right about context, json-ld is indeed not working as well as structured markup, which doesn't have this issue - you can see comparison by using https://silver-picayune-cork.glitch.me/. There are no errors for relative urls in markup vs json-ld. This makes me wonder if js is being used for parsing markup, as when you use document.links[0].href and href is a relative url, you still get absolute back. Oh well, I'll stick to structured markup when possible.Bonus: it seems you can generate json-ld client side, so adding base url is very easy - use this for your own risk :)

Answer (score 1):

All URLs should be absolute.
You can use the official testing tool https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/ that is going to give an error in relative URLs.

Comment: That was not the case when I posted the question. Thanks for your answer, I'll have a look at it when I have a moment.

Comment: At the moment of writing this comment google structured data tool was not giving an error for relative urls. However it appends https://search.google.com domain in front of them.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment I can see that structured markup tool shows errors for images that have relative urls for article type. This is so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it should be ok.

Check: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool

Example test data with relative urls:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
  "itemListElement": [{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 1,
    "item": {
      "@id": "http://www.example.com/",
      "name": "Home"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 2,
    "item": {
      "@id": "/furniture/",
      "name": "Furniture"
    }
  },{
    "@type": "ListItem",
    "position": 3,
    "item": {
      "@id": "/furniture/kitchen/",
      "name": "Kitchen"
    }
  }]
}
</script>
```

*Update*
Just checked once more:
Oh google add domain http://www.example.com/ for items without absolute url in the output of structure data testing tool. So discard my message, I am not sure if the relative paths are supported, use absolute instead.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the first  link being required to be absolute. The tool returns no errors or warnings when all URLs are relative.

Comment: Ignore my message about first link

Comment: @rzasap: It’s no problem that Google displays the example domain for relative URLs; it’s a common practice in tools like that (I guess they do it to convey to their users that the value *does* get interpreted as URL, not just as text string).

Comment: @rzasap I ended up externalising all the URLs anyway as I had to rewrite the paths. I still think relative ones are fine as the validator does not consider this an error and I'd expect the domain that the JSON-LD document is served from will be assumed as the host.

Answer (score 0):

Google accepts "relative" URLs that begin with #. On the other hand, since Google accepts "injected" or "constructed" JSON-LD using JavaScript, relative URLs can be easily turned into absolute URLs upon rendering (typically via onload event). Relative URLs are also accepted and recognized by Google Rich Results test as absolute URLs when declared using RFDa and Microdata syntax.